# Import text file to SQL Server using Bulk Insert

Tags: sql-server, bulk-import

This is my sql

```
BULK INSERT dbo.Account FROM 'G:\Import\Account3.txt'
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '" | "'
)
GO
```

When I run the sql i got this error

> Msg 4866, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> The bulk load failed.

The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 1. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.

> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>
> Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
> Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

Please help me. I already tried many ways but still get the same error.

Comment: Please also post some sample rows from Account3.txt

Answer (score 5):

From your example SQL, it seems you are missing a ROWTERMINATOR statement, specifying how rows are to be differentiated from one another.

Your query would then become something like

```sql
BULK INSERT dbo.Account FROM 'G:\Import\Account3.txt'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = '" | "',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n'
)
GO
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
BULK
INSERT dbo.Account 
FROM 'G:\Import\Account3.txt'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = '|',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

Comment: When I run this script i got this error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'. I Hope somebody can help me. This is my first time do this

Comment: I tried to user another script but still get the same error. This is my new script USE Reporting_DB_Test;
GO
BULK INSERT dbo.Account
   FROM 'G:\Import\Account.txt'
   WITH (
   CHECK_CONSTRAINTS,
      FIELDTERMINATOR = '" | "',
      KEEPNULLS ,
      CODEPAGE='RAW',
      KEEPIDENTITY
   );
GO    Please I really need help.